# Не приходит объект из Бота ТГ

Tags: php, telegram-bot, бот

Пишу бота в ТГ на PHP. Столкнулся с проблемой, что при отправке сообщения, объект не попадает в логи, хотя сам файл логов создается. Подключение есть, все написано корректно. В чем может быть причина?! Спасибо!
Код прилагаю:

```
const TOKEN = '192940//1540:AAHNmo00-ctABeU1kvdJpYyhuZs'; // Link:  t.me/luxpereezdTest_bot.
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/';

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/logs.txt', print_r($update, 1), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Причина в том что `$update` содержит значение, которое превращается в пустую строку. Например NULL.

Comment: Cпасибо, а что нужно сделать, чтобы это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо проверять на пустоту содержимое переменной перед записью в файл:

```py
const TOKEN = '192940//1540:AAHNmo00-ctABeU1kvdJpYyhuZs'; 
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/';

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

if(empty($update)){
exit(1);
}

file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/logs.txt', print_r($update, 1), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Почему-то не помогает..( Уже переgробовал все аргументы json_decode...

Comment: `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))`